# Continuity of identiy mapping in the weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-topology

I am trying to show that the identity mapping $$id :(M,\parallel \parallel) \longrightarrow (E,\sigma(E,E^*)) $$ is continuous. such that $E$ is a normed space and $M$ a vector subspace of $E$. Using the fact that induced topology on M by the weak topology of E are the same. $$ \sigma(M,M^*) = \sigma(E,E^*)\cap M$$
What I have tried so far : if we consider $O$ an open subset in $\sigma(E,E^*) $
$$id^{-1}(O) = O \cap M$$ which is open in the weak toplogy in $M$. But this doesn't prove that $id^{-1}(O)$ is open in $M$ strongly
.

Comment: Write to out the definition of the neighbourhood basis of the weak topology; it should be suggestive. Also, what are the relations between $E$ and $M$?

Comment: All we know is that M is a linear subspace of E

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Every weakly open subset is strongly open.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks. Then my reasoning should be correct